# How can I stop WordPress from catching URL's for static pages that I save on my server

Tags: htaccess, html, customization

I posted a question about whether it's possible to add a Page in WordPress without headers and footers.

Here's that question: [Add a Page without header and menus?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60000/add-a-page-without-header-and-menus)

So how can I create a static page with none of the WordPress stuff that appears on all the other pages of my WordPress site, and add html at that url?

How would I do that?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, showing arbitrary html at a URL is already possible using page templates or just raw post markup and a page template.

Comment: It also looks like rather than clarifying your question and editing it, you've just created a new one that's asking the same thing =/

Comment: the answers you got on that question gave you the answer to this one.

Comment: I answered at the original question. No need for this duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Richard

To be honest I think you are asking `How can I stop WordPress from responding to URL's for static pages that I save in other directories on my server`

Basically its in 2 files

- your VHOST (which maps mydomain.com to www/some_folder/ )
- your .htaccess file which manages redirects

So you can do 2 things ...
1. get a new VHOST for subdomain so something-mydomain.com maps to another a folder on your server - or -
2. update your .htaccess file to include redirect urls

your .htaccess file will pick up any requests for urls   BEFORE WordPress gets involved.

so you can have `mydomain.com` and WordPress will manage all requests and then create a rule that says `mydomain.com/this_page.html` is in   `www/some_folder/this_page.html`

here is an example of code for a redirect to a static page that you can add to your .htaccess file:

```
#static page redirects here
redirectMatch 301 ^/this_page(.*)$ /this_folder/this_page.htm'
```

Comment: Nice interpretation, seems legit :) If revealed correct, either you or @Richard should edit the Q to make this clear. Anyway, the Q **really deserves** some clarification...

Comment: @brasofilo cheers for that :)

Comment: @richard did that work?